# Data Object unable to summation inside the computed properties in VUE js 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, computed-properties

Let see the following code segment in vue.js 3,

```
<template>
  <div>
        <h2>Computed Total - {{getPrice()}}</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "ComputedProperties",
    data(){
        return{
            items: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'TV',
                    price: 100,
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'Phone',
                    price: 200,
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    title: 'Laptop',
                    price: 300
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        getPrice(){
            return items.reduce((total, curr) => (total = total + curr.price), 0)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

After run this code it is showing, `error  'items' is not defined  no-undef`
As we know that computed property doesn't need to declarer any argument. Then what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your code:

1. When using computed property, don't use `()` - it is a property, not a function

`<h2>Computed Total - {{ getPrice }}</h2>`

2. All members of `data`, `computed` or `methods` when used in the `script` part of the Vue component, must be referenced with `this` ...for example `this.items`

```js
computed: {
        getPrice() {
            return this.items.reduce((total, curr) => total + curr.price, 0)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have changed it as <h2>Computed Total - {{ getPrice }}</h2> but still same problem is in here...:(